# Query with multiple joins ends in wrong result

Tags: mysql

I have a query, which result is incorrect, but can't figure out, how it will work correct.
Here is a diagram of my actual database layout:
[image: Database Diagram]

I try to achieve to get all articles and sold amounts which are within a specific date from table "auftrag"
But it seems, that my result brings back all articles from the "auftragdetails" table.
Can someone help me out with that?
My actual SQL is:

```
SELECT
  invnrbeschreibung.Beschreibung AS Inventory,
  TRIM(CONCAT(lieferanten.Anschrift1, ' ', IFNULL(lieferanten.Anschrift2, ''))) AS Supplier,
  brand.Name AS Brand,
  aufDetail.artikelnr AS ArticleNumber,
  aufDetail.groesse AS Size,
  aufDetail.farbe AS Color,
  aufDetail.ArtikelBezeichnung AS Description,
  SUM(aufDetail.menge) AS Sold
FROM auftrag auf
  INNER JOIN auftragdetails aufDetail
    ON auf.id = aufDetail.auftragid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN artikelstamm article
    ON aufDetail.artikelid = article.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN brand
    ON article.BrandID = brand.ID
  INNER JOIN invnrbeschreibung
    ON article.InvNr = invnrbeschreibung.InvNr
  INNER JOIN lieferanten
    ON lieferanten.Lieferant = article.Lieferant
WHERE auf.AufDat BETWEEN DATE('01.07.2019') AND DATE('31.07.2019')
GROUP BY aufDetail.artikelid
```

THX in advance

Comment: Simplify the problem, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: For instance, only aufdetail and auf are relevant to your actual problem

Comment: No, the article itself is also relevant, because of the brand - and the brand is only stored within the articles table and not in the "aufDetail" table

Comment: Sure, but (apparently) it's not the part of the problem with which you're struggling.

Comment: Also, note that dates adhere to a specific format in MySQL. DATE() is meaningless in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute this:

```
select DATE('01.07.2019') date1, DATE('31.07.2019') date2
```

the result is:

```
| date1      | date2      |
| ---------- | ---------- |
| 2001-07-20 | 2031-07-20 |
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/amwR5h5FVYLGJbxaexp3eg/1).
Pass the dates in the proper format:

```
DATE('2019-07-01') and DATE('2019-07-31')
```

or simply:

```
'2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31'
```

Comment: Absolutely. I think @forpas found the reason of problem. BTW, it is not given which data type is used for `auftrag`.`aufDat`. Even if the information stored as 'DD-MM-YYYY' (in varchar field) it cannot be used as data.